# Backing up a device and restoring it including its partitions

Tags: partition, backup, grub, fdisk, gpt

Currently I'm going through each partition doing:

```
mount -o rw /dev/mmcblk1pX /mnt/pX
cd /mnt/pX
# backing up:
tar -czvf /tmp/partitionX.tar.gz .
...
# something went wrong, restoring:
tar -xzvf /tmp/partitionX.tar.gz
```

I'm using GPT:

```
Device            Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1     2048    22527    20480  10M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk1p2    22528 10508287 10485760   5G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p3 10508288 25188351 14680064   7G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p4 25188352 39868415 14680064   7G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p5 39868416 41965567  2097152   1G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p6 41965568 50354175  8388608   4G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p7 50354176 50358271     4096   2M BIOS boot
/dev/mmcblk1p8 50358272 54552575  4194304   2G Linux filesystem
```

What's a good and fast way of backing up a device with partitions and restoring them later? The current way gets tiring. The BIOS boot partition I generate via grub-install.
I have an EFI system partition because the device should be bootable in UEFI and BIOS mode.

Comment: Use [dd](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-dd-create-make-disk-image-commands/) command.

Comment: More information would help I think - what are the different partitions used for?  Are they all part of the same root filesystem or are they different OSes for example?  Also do you want to also backup the partition table and recreate it during a restore operation?  My initial advice is just to script what you already do.  However do not use dd as that is definitely not quick, in fact it's probably the slowest method.

Comment: @BlueManCZ can you formulate the `dd` route as an answer. The way I'm applying it is too slow. I tested it with a 1GiB partition and it never finished after 30 minutes of waiting.

Comment: @JohnHawthorne Second partition is the root filesystem/OS partition 3 to 6 are mounted to the root system. Partition 8 is a standalone OS used for recovery. Partition 1 is needed for booting in UEFI mode. Partition 7 is needed for booting in Legacy/BIOS mode. I'll look into writing a script but I'm unsure if my way of doing it is optimal or not.

Comment: @TinNguyen I don't want formulate it as answer, but something like `dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 of=/tmp/backupfile bs=64K conv=noerror,sync` should create image of your `/dev/mmcblk1` drive with all its partitions into file `/tmp/backupfile`. For restoring you just swap paths. But as @JohnHawthorne says, I don't know how fast it is. And always be careful when you work with drives, you can loose your data.

Comment: You should test it on something not so much important for you.